# Python Export Decorator

Tags: python, api, meta-programming, modules, namespaces

In Python, we use [`__all__` to explicitly denote the public API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44834/541136) of a module or package. That looks like this:

```
__all__ = ['Foo', 'bar', 'BAZ_CONSTANT']

BAZ_CONSTANT = None

class Foo:
    pass

def bar():
    pass
```

... except that modules can go on for thousands of lines, and then it is not immediately apparent, without revisiting the heading of the file, which objects are for external use, and which are not.

We are also required to write the names of the objects *twice* for each of these objects. (At a minimum. Even more for unittests - and we write our tests first, don't we?)

What I want is a decorator that allows me to shift the declaration of the public API away from the heading and to the object and constant definitions, where we, in most cases, can only write the name to be exported *once*.

Here's a serviceable preliminary draft, targeted to Python 3.6+ - perhaps the simplest thing that could possibly work:

```
import sys

class ExportError(Exception):
    """Exception if redundant names attempted exporting"""

def export(obj, global_namespace: dict=None) -> 'obj arg':
    """export adds names of functions and classes via decorator
    and module level variables via call (with globals() argument)
    to __all__.
    Usage:
    from exportlib import export

    export("BAZ_CONSTANT", globals()) # I don't like globals() call...
    BAZ_CONSTANT = None

    @export
    class Foo: 
        pass

    @export
    def bar(): 
        pass
    """
    name = obj if isinstance(obj, str) else obj.__name__
    if global_namespace is None:
         try:
             global_namespace = obj.__globals__
         except AttributeError as error:
             raise AttributeError(
               f'no globals, try export({name!r}, globals())')
    __all__ = global_namespace.setdefault('__all__', [])
    if name in __all__: # Do we care if redundant exports? Assuming so:
        raise ExportError(f'{name} already exported')
    __all__.append(name)
    return obj
```

Ok, could probably be a little simpler with fewer features. I do like the documenting features of the annotations. I couldn't identify a more appropriate Exception to subclass or use directly than `Exception`.

I don't like the `globals()` call required when adding a module level variable that doesn't know its own name or module, but the only alternative, that I can think of, is to do what `super` does and climb a stackframe up and get the globals there, or pass in `__all__` instead (which would require creating it explicitly). Stackframe climbing would preclude `export` from being wrapped/extended.

But I think this makes a sufficiently sophisticated starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Personally, I'd prefer to use `@export()` or `@export(globals())`, rather than manually perform the `@` sugar.
- I don't like using `__globals__`, [even if it is writeable](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy).
- Honestly, I think the cleanest solution would be to abuse lists, and use a closure.
- I do however agree that inheriting from `Exception`, is the best parent to inherit from.

And so I'd personally use something more like:

```
class ExportError(Exception):
    """Exception if redundant names attempted exporting"""

def build_export(__all__=None):
    if __all__ is None:
        __all__ = []
    def export(obj):
        name = obj if isinstance(obj, str) else obj.__name__
        if name in __all__:
            raise ExportError(f'{name} already exported')
        __all__.append(name)
        return obj
    return __all__, export


__all__, export = build_export()


@export
class Foo:
    pass


@export
def bar():
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's too much magic, I worry about static linters and new users not understanding the code, so I would want to support proper global variable assignment.

On the other hand, Peilonrayz's answer seems overly rigid - returning a tuple? I'd like those who would want minimalist usage to be able to have it.

### First a disclaimer

I'd never submit this code for review at work or on Python-dev for inclusion in the standard library.

The existing mechanism is fine, even if it is redundant, and I think there's a benefit to declaring the API at the top instead of scattered throughout.

And even if my code works perfectly bug-free, its existence could lead to the easy introduction of further bugs.

### Suggestion

How about a list subclass that implements `__call__` to decorate functions/classes?

```
import inspect

class ExportError(Exception):
    """Exception if redundant names attempted exporting"""

class Export(list):
    __slots__ = 'global_namespace',
    def __init__(self, *obj, **globals_):
        self.global_namespace = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals
        self.global_namespace.setdefault('__all__', self)
        self(*obj, **globals_)
    def __call__(self, *obj, **globals_):
        for obj_ in obj:
            if isinstance(obj_, str):
                for name in obj_.split():
                    self.append_name(name)
            else:
                self.append_name(obj_.__name__)
        self.extend(globals_)
        self.global_namespace.update(globals_)
        return obj[0] if obj else None
    def append_name(self, name):
        if name in self:
            raise ExportError(f'{name} already exported')
        self.append(name)
```

The downside of accessing the globals this way is that the `__init__` can't be extended in a subclass. Plus it just seems hack-y.

### Usage

Clean import (kinda funny to read out loud though):

```
from exportlib import Export
```

Clean assignment for the benefit of IDEs that understand `__all__`:

```
__all__ = export = Export()
```

We have the following minimalist usage supported - but it is potentially confusing to add to globals this way for static linting, like pyflakes - and even experienced users could be confused:

```
export = Export(
  BAZ_CONSTANT=None,
)
```

So we also support this slightly more verbose usage - which also supports annotations:

```
__all__ = export = Export('BAZ_CONSTANT', 'QUUX_CONSTANT')

BAZ_CONSTANT = None
QUUX_CONSTANT: None = None
```

Finally, we allow the namedtuple style single string API, splitting on the spaces:

```
__all__ = export = Export('BAZ_CONSTANT QUUX_CONSTANT')

BAZ_CONSTANT = None
QUUX_CONSTANT: None = None
```

And other objects get decorated and added to `__all__`:

```
@export
class Foo: 
    pass

@export
def bar(): 
    pass
```

### Interactive Sessions

Here's an interactive session:

```
>>> __all__ = export = Export('BAZ_CONSTANT QUUX_CONSTANT')
>>> 
>>> BAZ_CONSTANT = None
>>> QUUX_CONSTANT: None = None
>>> 
>>> __all__
['BAZ_CONSTANT', 'QUUX_CONSTANT']
>>> 
>>> @export
... class Foo: 
...     pass
... 
>>> @export
... def bar(): 
...     pass
... 
>>> __all__
['BAZ_CONSTANT', 'QUUX_CONSTANT', 'Foo', 'bar']
```

Both style checkers *and* new users should find the code easy to understand.

Here's the Proof of Concept (POC) for the minimalist usage as well - if this got into the standard library (inconceivable), then this usage could get into common practice and style checkers would need to be updated:

```
>>> export = Export(
...   BAZ_CONSTANT=None,
... )
>>> BAZ_CONSTANT is None
True
>>> __all__
['BAZ_CONSTANT']
>>> @export
... class Foo: 
...     pass
... 
>>> @export
... def bar(): 
...     pass
... 
>>> __all__
['BAZ_CONSTANT', 'Foo', 'bar']
```

### Final acceptance test

Finally, putting `Export` into `exportlib.py`
and the above minimalist-style code into `user.py`, we test `import *` (which can be appropriately used to provision an API point.) If this works, this should fully test the globals lookup in the `__init__`:

```
$ python -i
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import user
>>> from user import *
>>> dir()
['BAZ_CONSTANT', 'Foo', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__',
 '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'bar', 'user']
>>> BAZ_CONSTANT is None
True
```

And it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Your minimalist version is, IMO, un-Pythonic. "[There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)". I don't know why you hate returning a tuple, the usage, for users, is almost exactly the same as yours, and it's easier to understand. Finally, I don't see how mine is ridged, what more features would you want? And how would sub classing help that?